# Using same data and methods in different components

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to create an app that will have hundreds of pages and i need something, a sigle file, where I can define the array of pages and the methods to navigate trough them. This data and methods will have to be imported and accessable from different components and pages.
I'm not sure exactly what I should create. I've thought about @viewchild but that should go with a template and I don't have (or need) one, right now I need to manage just datas and methods. Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for services.

Services are used for interactions between components.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Comment: yes, you and Rahul are right. I've looked into services (and providers for ionic 2) and that seems to be the right way. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT_ after some coding I found out that services are not a raccomanded option if you want to use NavController. I'm just leaving this here so no one goes on the wrong road like I did.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will have to go for services to have methods that multiple components can use. But if your components use the same data across the application then for application maintainability you can take help of redux i:e flux architecture.

Take a look at this repo that has services and also a demo to redux using ngrx in angular.Its being created by me for Angular concepts.

https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You will try import some model library like [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) to your project, and in Redux Singleton Store put all your data and methods?

Comment: I know you are new, and we want you to do well here. Takes a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer